# Is the answer "positive" to the question "How are you" - considered acceptable?

Tags: word-usage

Is the answer "**positive**" to the question "**How are you**" - considered acceptable in meaning of "I am OK"? I have tried to get an answer in a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/positive?q=POSITIVE), but I couldn't find it there, therefore as the last resort I have chosen to use the wisdom of the crowd.

> Questioner: **How are you**?
>
> The person who answers: **positive**.

N.B. If you answer I'd like to know whether your answer represents British or American English.

Comment: Remember that the meaning of the question can vary between AmE and BrE - often in BrE we don’t actually want to know how you’re doing - we just expect a “good thanks, you?” response, no matter how you’re feeling.

Answer (score 19):

As an American English speaker, it doesn't sound natural to me.

**Original Conversation**

> **Q:** How are you?
>
> **A:** * [I'm] positive.

In this case, I'd interpret *I'm positive* to mean that they were certain about something. Since *I'm certain* doesn't make sense as an answer to the question, I wouldn't understand what was intended.

**Alternative Conversation**

> **Q:** How are you?
>
> **A:** I'm **feeling** positive.

In this case, I'd understand that the person was saying they felt hopeful, rather than certain.

As pointed out in the comments, this response still only really makes sense when there’s some sort of context that makes it clear what the person is hopeful or optimistic about (ht: topo morto, Mr Lister).

Comment: I'm British and I would have given the same answer.

Comment: I tend to think 'feeling positive' makes most sense when it's clear what particular thing the person is positive *about*. I don't often hear it as a general description of someone's state.

Comment: Same here. I'm not a native English speaker, but "positive" in this context would mean "optimistic" to me. You can't be "positive" in general, you can only be positive _about_ something. Unless you mean you are positive about _everything_, which would be a tad weird.

Comment: Very good points. Updated the answer to reflect the need for context.

Comment: I think also that 'positive' in medical connotation can be about antibodies or antigens carriers.

Comment: @Archimedean_Point I'm not so sure about antibodies (because I've never heard the term used for them), but I'm pretty sure that it's not antigens meant but the actual disease / infection. And that's only used colloquially in certain situations (I'm not sure which).

Comment: @Archimedean_Point You mean, if the person asking "how are you" is really inquiring about the results of the test. Yes. Yet another different context.

Comment: @MrLister I was thanking you and topo morto for your suggestion on how to improve the answer (ht = hat tip).

Answer (score 4):

The standard answer is "I am fine, thank you. How are you?" Referring to the common answers in "Business" or polite "British English". You can also say: "I'm doing well" or "I'm doing good" (informal). Answering with "positive" would be suitable to the question "How do you feel about it?"

Answer (score 2):

In Canadian English, '**I'm positive**' in response to '**How are you?**'
sounds like you tested positive on a medical test. like pregnancy.
but without a previous context of a medical test, it's non sequitur.